# FormsAuthentication is not declared

Tags: vb.net, forms-authentication

I'm using VB.NET 2010.

One of my lines of code is:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(TextBox_AccessCode.Text, "MD5"))
```

But FormsAuthentication is underlined and the error reads 'FormsAuthentication' is not declared.  I've ensured that the System.Web.Security namespace is imported, yet I still receive the message.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Just a Windows Form application.

Answer (score 0):

FormsAuthentication forms part of the System.Web that is used in asp.net and is not accessibly through Win Forms. Not entirely sure if you will be able to import the dll and use it that way, I doubt it...

If you just want to hash a md5 string you can do below:

```
new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox_AccessCode.Text);
x.ComputeHash(bs);
```

Comment: Thanks for that information, but that does not apply to VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to TBohnen.jnr, I found that Forms Authentication is not a part of Windows Forms via VB.NET.  I ended up using the following code to generate an MD5 hash:

```
    Public Shared Function MD5(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim provider As MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim bytValue() As Byte
    Dim bytHash() As Byte
    Dim strOutput As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    provider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    bytValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)
    bytHash = provider.ComputeHash(bytValue)
    provider.Clear()
    For i = 0 To bytHash.Length - 1
        strOutput &= bytHash(i).ToString("x").PadLeft(2, "0")
    Next
    Return strOutput
End Function
```